# Merge two lists into a dictionary and sum over the elements of the second list

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

If I have two lists (with the same length):

```
ls1 = ['a','b','c','a','d','c']
ls2 = [1,2,3,5,1,2]
```

I would like to get the following dictionary (sum over the values if it is the same key):

```
d = {'a':6,'b':2,'c':5,'d':1}
```

I did the following:

```
ls1 = np.array(ls1)
ls2 = np.array(ls2)
uniqe_vals = list(set(ls1))
d = {}
for u in uniqe_vals:
    ind = np.where(ls1 == u)[0]
    d[u] = sum(ls2[ind])
```

It works fine for small data, but it is taking too long for the whole data (I have a list of size ~5 million). 
Do you have any suggestions for a more efficient way to do it ?

Comment: I really don't know too much about how efficient numpy arrays and `np.where` are, but without numpy I would make d a `defaultdict(int)`, and simply iterate over `izip(ls1,ls2)` and add the value of from ls2 to the element in the dictionary with the key from ls1. That's just a guess though and might possibly be way less efficient than your solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also with a defaultdict, but different and simpler:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for n, v in zip(ls1, ls2):
   d[n] += v
```

Or, as suggested:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools   import izip

d = defaultdict(int)
for n, v in izip(ls1, ls2):
   d[n] += v
```

Comment: `collections.izip` instead of `zip`, so it doesn't need to build the list first.

Comment: Note that there is a potential bug here. It may be undesired behavior to have the dict return 0 for every value not in the original lists.

Comment: If that is an issue, one can always convert it back to a normal dictionary, or alternatively use a more complicated line to add v, using `.get`

Comment: A conversion should normally not be needed (but it is possible, of course), since the "in" operator can be used as normal and also when you iterate over the keys, only those touched will be listed.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
import numpy as np
uni, i = np.unique(ls1, return_inverse=1)
vals = np.bincount(i, ls2)
dict(zip(uni, vals))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked how to make it more efficient, I compared the time your original solution took with the version suggested in my comment (equivalent with Juergen's second solution) with 5 million random characters from a-z as keys and 5 million random values from 0-20, using my shell's `time` function:

```
~/test $ time python defdict.py
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 381956, 'c': 383815, 'b': 378277, 'e': 384629, 'd': 383557, 'g': 381139, 'f': 386268, 'i': 383902, 'h': 385809, 'k': 385138, 'j': 384690, 'm': 388552, 'l': 384393, 'o': 384533, 'n': 385011, 'q': 385685, 'p': 386188, 's': 387132, 'r': 383886, 'u': 386176, 't': 387144, 'w': 386371, 'v': 388263, 'y': 381337, 'x': 385281, 'z': 384048})
python defdict.py  13,24s user 0,35s system 96% cpu 14,045 total

~/test $ time python original.py
{'a': 386316, 'c': 383596, 'b': 383424, 'e': 385598, 'd': 383324, 'g': 382233, 'f': 385435, 'i': 386761, 'h': 384047, 'k': 386640, 'j': 386313, 'm': 381032, 'l': 383035, 'o': 389142, 'n': 385000, 'q': 386088, 'p': 387435, 's': 385429, 'r': 384260, 'u': 385442, 't': 384793, 'w': 385052, 'v': 380830, 'y': 386500, 'x': 386871, 'z': 379870}
python original.py  14,68s user 0,38s system 96% cpu 15,529 total
```

So there seems to be a difference, although not a big one. To make it fairer, numpy was also imported in `defdict.py`.